# solutions of Differentially uniform mappings for cryptography

Tags: roots, finite-fields, cryptography

Kaisa Nyberg provided a proof of number of zeros in inverse mapping in finite field [ref](http://www.science.unitn.it/~caranti/Didattica/SymCrypt/static/Refs/DifferentiallyUniform.pdf). The proof is clear for me except the final step where  she proved that the following equation has two solution when n is odd in $GF(2^n)$ and 4 solutions when n is even:

$x(x^3 +\alpha^3)= 0$

**Q1)** she applied $gcd(3,2^n-1)=1$ for her proof. could you please explain how to use gcd in finding zeros in $GF(2^n)$?

**Q2)** I extended her approach to apply for $(x+\alpha)^{-2} - x^{-2}=\beta$ and obtained $x^{2}(x^6 +\alpha^6)= 0$  in $GF(2^n)$ . I got stuck to prove the number of zeros when n is odd and even. i took this approach to understand the mathematical motivation taken for one of the Aria cipher sbox ($x^{247}=x^{-8}$). could you please help me to continue proof number of solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1**

From the equation
$$
x(x^3+\alpha^3)=0
$$
we know that one of the roots is $x=0$, for the rest we want to solve
$$
x^3+\alpha^3=0 \Longleftrightarrow x^3 = -\alpha^3 = \alpha^3
$$
If $g$ is a generator of $GF(2^n)$, then $\alpha = g^v$ for some integer $0\leq v < 2^n-1$ (since $\alpha\neq 0$). We may also write $x=g^u$ for some integer $0\leq u<2^n-1$, so the equation becomes
$$
g^{3u} = g^{3v} \in GF(2^n) \Longleftrightarrow 3u\equiv 3v \pmod{2^n-1}
$$
Now if $3$ does not divide $2^n-1$, which is where the $\gcd(3,2^n-1)=1$ comes from, then we can multiply by inverse of $3$ to get
$$
u \equiv v \pmod{2^n-1}
$$
Since both $u,v$ are in $[0,2^n-1)$, there is only 1 distinct root possible, which is $u=v$. This is the obvious root $x=g^u=g^v = \alpha$. Hence there are only two roots in total, $0$ and $\alpha$.

I think it is quite common to shorten these type of argument like the following:

> Let $G$ be a cyclic multiplicative group with order $m$ and $\alpha\in G$. Then
>   $$x^k = \alpha^k$$
>   has only 1 root if $\gcd(k,m)=1$".

---

For the other case where $3\mid 2^n-1$, let $m=2^n-1 = 3d$. The equation is now
$$
\begin{align}
3u &\equiv 3v \pmod{3d}\\
u &\equiv v \pmod d
\end{align}
$$
Let $r\equiv v \pmod d$ such that $0\leq r < d$. Then $u$ can take 3 solutions $u=r, r+d, r+2d$. Since $0\leq r,r+d,r+2d < 3d = 2^n-1$, we know that the elements $g^r,g^{r+d},g^{r+2d}$ are distinct. So we have 4 roots in total: $x=0,g^r,g^{r+d},g^{r+2d}$.

Finally: When $n$ is odd $3$ does not divide $2^n-1$ so by the first part there are two solution. Otherwise $n$ is even, $3$ divies $2^n-1$ so by the second part there are four solutions.

---

The text writes $d=(2^n-1)/3$ and suggests that the two other roots are $x=\alpha^{1+d}$ and $x=\alpha^{1+2d}$. Now these roots do satisfy the equation, say:
$$
x^3+\alpha^3 = (\alpha^{1+d})^3+\alpha^3 = \alpha^{3+m}+\alpha^3 = \alpha^3 + \alpha^3 = 0
$$
(Since $\alpha^m=1$ by Lagrange's Theorem.) The same happens for $x=\alpha^{1+2d}$. However I don't think it's quite right since these roots can be repeated, for example if $\alpha=1$ then following the text you get the roots $0,1,1,1$. Using the method above you first get $\alpha = 1 = g^0$, then the roots are $0,g^0,g^d,g^{2d}$. Maybe I am missing some context where repeated roots cannot happen.

---

**Q2**
Similarly, for the equation 
$$
x^2(x^6 + \alpha^6)=0
$$
we see immediately a (repeated) root of $x=0$. The rest of the roots lie in 
$$
x^6 + \alpha^6 = 0
$$
Since the field is characteristic two, we have
$$
(x^3+\alpha^3)^2 = x^6+\alpha^6 = 0
$$
Therefore we are reduced to
$$
x^3 + \alpha^3 = 0
$$
This has exactly the same roots as before, depending on whether $n$ is odd or even.